# Faces4 -- f:validateWholeBean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-validation

I want to use the  <f:validateWholeBean> Tag to validate multiple values in my BackingBean. I started with [this example](https://hantsy.gitbook.io/java-ee-8-by-example/jsf/jsf-validatewholebean), but I got stuck somehow.

I added

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.validator.ENABLE_VALIDATE_WHOLE_BEAN</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to my `web.xml`.

In contrast to the example (which uses two textfields), I want to use the validation for the values of multiple `h:selectOneMenu`-Fields in a `h:dataTable`

```
<h:form id="getPortPropsForm">

   <h:dataTable value="#{ctl.portList}" var="port">

      <h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">#{msg['portName']}</f:facet>
         <h:inputText id="name" value="#{port.name}" required="true" />             
       </h:column>
       ...
       <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">#{msg['portMac']}</f:facet>

          <h:selectOneMenu id="sel" value="#{port.macAddr}" required="true">
             <f:selectItems value="#{ctl.list}" var="m" itemValue="#{m.mac}"/>
             <f:validator validatorId="free_mac_validator"/>
             <f:validateBean validationGroups="javax.validation.groups.Default ,my.UniqueMacValidationGroup"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>              
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

    <h:commandButton id="submit" update="@form" value="save" action="#{ctl.persist()}">
       <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":globalMessages"/>
    </h:commandButton>        

    <f:validateWholeBean validationGroups="my.UniqueMacValidationGroup" value="#{ctl}"/>
</h:form>
```

My BackingBean

```
@ConversationScoped
@Named("ctl")
@UniqueMac(groups = UniqueMacValidationGroup.class)
public class AddSwitchController implements Serializable, MacHolder, Cloneable {
    ...
    @NotNull(groups = UniqueMacValidationGroup.class)
    @Override
    public List<Mac> getMacAddresses() {
        ... 
        return macList;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public AddSwitchController clone() {
       ...
    }
}
```

implements a methode which can be called by the validator

```
public class UniqueMacValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueMac, MacHolder> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueMac constraintAnnotation) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MacHolder macHolder, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        List<Mac> macList = macHolder.getMacAddresses();
        ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

to get the values to check.

When I run the code, the `free_mac_validator` is called for every instance of the `h:selectOneMenu` and then I would expect my BackingBean to be cloned for the wholeBeanValidation, but the `clone` Method is not called and I don't see how to proceed.

I'm not looking for a workaround, I want to understand, how this whole-bean-validation-mechanism works.

Comment: I still got stuck with this issue, but I'm one step further. According to [the doc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/f/validatewholebean), calling the clone methode is the third option to use, when creating the copy of the BackingBean, got this.  Next step is "...Populate the copied bean with the candidate values....". This works well for all scalar values, but until now, I'm unable to get values for lists (everything I gather with <h:dataTable>, <ui:repeat> or <c:foreach>).